# In First Order Logic, why are we allowed infinitely long sets of finite formulas, but not infinite formulas?

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers

Consider the empty language $L = \{\}$. Then we are said to be able to define the set of infinitely many elements, say $K = \{x_1,\cdots,x_n,\cdots\}$, as the set satisfying the infinite set of finite formulas $\{ \phi_1,\cdots,\phi_n,\cdots \}$ where

$$\phi_n := \exists_{\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}} \bigwedge_{\{i, j: i \neq j\}}(x_i \neq x_j)$$

But this statement is equivalent to the infinite formula

$$ \exists_{\{x_1, \cdots, x_n, \cdots\}} \bigwedge_{\{i, j: i \neq j\}}(x_i \neq x_j).$$

I claim that every infinite formula can be equivalently expressed as an infinite set of finite formulas.

Thus I do not see why do we disallow the second but not the first?

Does disallowing infinite sets of finite formulas have a big impact on first order logic?

Comment: To make this claim, you need to first define what is "infinite formula", and I doubt you will be able to find a good definition. Remember that usually when checking if formula is true in model, we start by looking at the leftmost quantifier, but in "infinite formula" it is not a well-defined concept. Disallowing infinite sets of finite formulas will have some impact, for example PA isn't finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: @AnneBauval Indeed!

Comment: I disagree with @mihaild - you can define infinite formulas and indeed this is the subject of "infinitary logic" (and all sorts of interesting large cardinal facts!). However your claim "every infinite formula can be equivalently expressed as an infinite set of finite formulas" is false. There is an infinite disjunction which says  "the set is finite", but we know that there is no first-order axiomatisation of finite sets. What we normally allow amounts to "an infinite conjunction of finite formulas". We're interested in this because it's natural, and there are cool theorems about it!

Comment: In particular, theorems like the compactness theorem can't hold for all infinitary logics, exactly because the compactness theorem shows that any theory that has arbitrary large models must have an infinite model. "Disallowing infinite sets of finite formulas" is essentially the notion of "finite axiomatisability", as mihaild mentions. This is also interesting and there is a lot to read about it! Your example of "infinite sets" is also not finitely axiomatisable, by a standard argument (if it was axiomatised by a finite set of sentences, then we can express the negation in a single sentence..)

Comment: If finite axiomatizability limits us in the empty language by not allowing us to express infinite sets, how does it limit us in a language like $L = \{ F( \cdot , \cdot), G(\cdot , \cdot), R(\cdot , \cdot), a, b\}$, for example the structure $M = \{ +, \times, \leq, 0, 1 \}$? For example this language does allow us to express infinite sets, via the formula $\forall_{x_1} \exists_{x_2} x_1 \leq x_2$. Do we have compactness?

Answer (score 1):

The language $L_{\infty\omega}$ allows infinite disjunctions and conjunctions. It doesn’t allow infinitely deep chains of quantifiers, but you can easily rewrite your “infinitely many elements” example to abide by this restriction.

$L_{\infty\omega}$ has been extensively studied, and has interesting properties, but not the same properties as first-order logic. For example, the compactness theorem (perhaps the central tool in model theory) fails.

This is easy to see. The negation of the sentence “there are infinitely many elements” is also a formula of $L_{\infty\omega}$. Put this negation together with the infinite family of sentences “there are at least $n$ elements”, and you have a theory whose finite subtheories are all satisfiable, but which is not satisfiable.

So there are good reasons to study first-order theories, and not just $L_{\infty\omega}$.

Infinite conjunctions of sentences are equivalent to infinite families of sentences, as you’ve noticed. Not so infinite disjunctions. For example, “there are only finitely many elements” is easily expressed as an infinite disjunction, but cannot be expressed by an infinite family of sentences of first-order logic.

The notion of “type” in a first-order language serves as a quasi-substitute for an infinite conjunction, in some cases. The omitting types theorem can be regarded as saying something about satisfying an infinite disjunction.